# What's the difference between classes and libraries in programing languages?

Tags: java, c++, language-agnostic

For example in C++ I thought anything `#included` was a library, but then I see I am wrong for example `ifstream` is refereed to [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/&ei=wgXNUsZ9h_egBIyUgdgC&usg=AFQjCNEozUUefaQ3o86nVYWiJyzAvdKAzg&sig2=7OWJexlgQbiL4HVgAoteew) as a class. On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae1k9a9f.aspx) they don't use the word class or library.

If a library may offer classes or functions, then how is it different than a package (in the Java sense)?

Comment: A library is generally a collection of (related) classes.

Comment: And note that your MSDN link contains "class" in the first sentence.

Comment: `ifstream is a typedef that specializes the template class basic_ifstream for char` I admit I can't fully understand the sentence but to me it's not saying `ifstream` is a class. Am I mistaking?

Comment: A library is (at least in C++) a very loose term meaning something along the lines of "a collection of re-usable software components". It may contain classes, but it doesn't have to.

Comment: @user2864740 I thought that's what packages are for?

Comment: @user2864740 in C++, a library doesn't even have to contain any classes. I am saying that because, despite being tagged java and language-agnostic, the question seems to ask about C++.

Comment: @Celeritas `istream` is a typedef for `basic_ifstream` (understand "synonym"), which itself is a class. Take it as "`istream` is a class", it will behave like one anyway.

Comment: @aviad: You're trying to compare bicycles and airplanes.

Comment: @aviad no offense but it's very poor to joke when people are learning. In an intro course the teacher made a joke "boolean" is what a ghost said and from that point forward half the class thought "boolean" was a joke.

Comment: @Celeritas, I'm sorry you feel that way. However, your question does not show any real effort to understand the topics you are talking about before posting on SO.

Comment: @aviad no need to be sorry just learn from your mistake and don't make jokes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be perfectly language-agnostic, a library would be conceptually a collection of features. Period. It may offer functions, it may offer classes to create instance of (in languages that have classes, some don't have that concept).

A class is an Object Oriented Programmation concept which describes an entity which has (possibly) data and (possibly) behaviors (or functions/methods), with notions of encapsulation through the use of public/private access to data and/or functions.

As you tagged C++ and Java, I'll answer a bit more precisely regarding these languages. Both have classes (Java has more than classes, it works *only* through classes). You can find libraries for these languages that can offer a set of classes and functions (in Java, that could be done for example with static functions accessible without any instance of the class it belongs to).

Now about your example:

In C++, you include headers. They can come from libraries. You mentioned `ifstream` which is a class part of the C++ standard library, accessible through a header of this standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The library is a compilation of different classes(in c++/c#, classes are packed in .dll format. in java classes are packed in .jar format). Some libraries contain classes that provides services for specific functions. Whereas some libraries contain classes for all-sorts of tasks.

A class is an implementation of a certain behavior using a programming language in the object oriented way.

Answer (score 0):

In general we consider that a library means a collection of classes which helps to develop software. 
But it is not true for every language existing in this world. A library may contain a certain number of classes but it's not mandatory to have that, it may contain subroutine or type def or anything of that sort.

Where a class provides a specific functionality or few specific ones.

Now it depends on the language how they set the structure of their library or user accessibility to it.